# Getting "Dimension too large" using psgraph and listplot

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am trying to setup a chart.
Sometimes the y-Axis Value range gets a little narrow.
And in one of those cases I ran into the infamous "Dimension too large" error as seen below.

How can I circumvent that error, it seems to be related to the integrated AXIS parameters in the optional parameters of psgraph.

hence...

```
\begin{psgraph}[optionals... going to axis](xmin,ymin)(xmax,ymax){width,length}
\end{psgraph}
```

I hope the following qualifies as a MWE... ;)

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, headsepline, parskip, headinclude]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{pstricks-add}

    \begin{document}
        \def\dataI{%
        40 0.01
        30 0.008
        15 0.001
        0 0}

        \large Works fine\\
        \normalsize Using y-Max = 0.1 and Dy = 0.02

        \psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,plotstyle=line,tickstyle=top,axesstyle=frame}
        \begin{psgraph}[Dx=5,Dy=0.02](0,0)(0,0)(40,0.1){0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
            \listplot[linecolor=red]{\dataI}%
        \end{psgraph}

        \large Throws an error trying to magnify \emph{y} by one magnitude

        \small\begin{verbatim}
        % ! Dimension too large.
        % <recently read> \p@ 
        %
        % l.59 ...,0)(40,0.01){0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
        %
        % I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
        % Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
        \end{verbatim}
        \normalsize Using y-Max = 0.01 and Dy = 0.002

        \psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,plotstyle=line,tickstyle=top,axesstyle=frame}
        \begin{psgraph}[Dx=5,Dy=0.002](0,0)(0,0)(40,0.01){0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
            \listplot[linecolor=red]{\dataI}%
        \end{psgraph}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX arithmetic is a pain. You can scale the values with `\pstScalePoints`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
    \def\dataI{%
    40 0.01
    30 0.008
    15 0.001
    0 0}

 \psset{plotstyle=line,tickstyle=top,axesstyle=frame,urx=2cm}
 \begin{psgraph}[Dx=5,Dy=0.02](0,0)(40,0.1){0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
 \listplot[linecolor=red]{\dataI}%
 \end{psgraph}
 %
 \psset{plotstyle=line,tickstyle=top,axesstyle=frame}
 \pstScalePoints(1,1){}{100 mul}
 \begin{psgraph}[Dx=5,Dy=0.002,dy=0.2\psyunit](0,0)(40,1){0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
  \listplot[linecolor=red]{\dataI}%
  \end{psgraph}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With PGFPlots, you don't have to worry about scaling the data yourself. Plus, you can compile the document using any compiler (`latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`,...):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [thick, red] table {
40 0.01
30 0.008
15 0.001
0 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```